# qt_visualizer tutorial pointcloud doesnt appear

Tags: pcl

I compiled PCL1.10.1 against VTK 8.2.0 and try to start using PCL in my QT Gui Project like pcl
s qt_visualizer tutorial.
https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/qt_visualizer.html#qt-visualizer

The pointcloud doesnt appear. The renderwindow works. I could change backgrundcolor and add a coordinateaxis.
[image]
I copied the code from doc/tutorials/content/sources/qt_visualizer

I used cmake 3.16.3. According to

```
dpkg -s libboost-dev | grep 'Version'
```

boost version is 1.71.0.0ubuntu2

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

changing

```
typedef pcl::PointXYZRGBA PointT;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointT> PointCloudT;
```

in pclviewer.h

to

```
typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> PointCloud;
```

solved my problem. Dont know why.